# Profile scroller app: how to go back to previous profile? (JS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to build a profile scroller-type app, and I am currently stuck on how I'm supposed to go back to the previous profile. See the code below:

```
let profiles = profileIterator(profiles); // array of objects stored in a separate .js file

//  Next Event
next.addEventListener("click", nextProfile);


// Next Profile Display
function nextProfile() {
    const currentProfile = profiles.next().value;
    if(currentProfile !== undefined) {
        name.innerHTML = `<h4>${currentProfile.name}</h4>`; // content on HTML page that will be changed
        text.innerHTML = `<p>${currentProfile.info}</p>`
        img.innerHTML = `<img src="${currentProfile.img}">`
        next.innerHTML = 'Next';
        previous.style.display = "inline-block";
        previous.innerHTML = 'PREVIOUS';
    } else {
    window.location.reload();
    }
}

function previousProfile() {
    const currentProfile = profiles.previous().value;
    if(currentProfile !== undefined) {
        name.innerHTML = `<h4>${currentProfile.name}</h4>`;
        text.innerHTML = `<p>${currentProfile.info}</p>`
        img.innerHTML = `<img src="${currentProfile.img}">`
    } else {
        window.location.reload();
    }
}

//  Profile Iterator

function profileIterator(profiles) {
    let nextIndex = 0;

    return {
        next: function() {
            return nextIndex < profiles.length
            ? { value: profiles[nextIndex++], done: false }
            : { done: true }
        },
        previous: function() {
            return nextIndex < profiles.length
            ? { value: profiles[nextIndex--], done: false }
            : { done: true}
        }
    };
}
```

It seemed pretty straightforward to me at first, but apparently, I am wrong as whenever I click the Previous button, instead of going through the previous profiles, it instead jumbles them up in no particular order, missing one of them entirely as well.

Any advice? Is there a way to set an HTML5 video element's attributes from Batch?

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that when returning .previous() you should check if nextIndex < profiles.length? For my first glance, there is no way for that to be false and maybe it's the source of your problems.